# How to correctly define char array

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Does anyone know how should `ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST` be defined to avoid compilation error in the line marked below, or where I can find more information about it?

```
#define ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST {(char)0x75, (char)0xB2, (char)0x00}

void testFunction(char * testChar)
{

}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   char test[] = ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST;

   testFunction(test);
   testFunction(ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST); // <- fails to compile this line of code

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your data is know at compile time, you can say `#define ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST "\x75\xB2"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
{(char)0x75, (char)0xB2, (char)0x00}
```

is an initializer list and is not itself an array (or a pointer) in C89.

You instead could use:

```
#define ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST "\x75\xB2"
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to cast the ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST, i.e

`testFunction((char[])ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST)`

or

`#define ASF_OBJECT_GUID_TEST (char[]){(char)...}`

Comment: The `(char)` casts inside the curly braces are not needed of course (you probably know this, so the comment is mostly for the OP).  Also, this is C99 only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Supposed I have defined many string literals which have 8 characters, and each 2 of them make actually the value of a byte. Is there a way to create a macro that would modify those string literals by adding a "\x" between every couple of characters like the following?

```
#define TEST SOME_MACRO("33698149")
```

Where TEST would be `"\x33\x69\x81\x49"`

Comment: This should be asked as a new question, or you should edit your original post to include this question.

Comment: Definitely a new question, although the short answer is "no, you can't do that".